# How to make UITableView cell separator like iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In iOS 7 , default `UITableViewCell` `separator` is a little bit cutting from left that can show cell's `imageView`.

I can change to full size with following codes.

```
[self.tableViewMain setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

And i want to change it when my iPad orientation is Portrait.

So i tried following codes in rotate event

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) ||(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)))
    {
        [self.tableViewMain setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }

    else
    {
        [self.tableViewMain setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
```

I want to do it like iOS7 Cell Separator manually.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

`[self.tableViewMain setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 0)];`

**EDIT:**

Above answer is wrong. Adding a custom `UIView` will solve this.
Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be lie this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UIView *lineView;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];

        [cell.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height-1)];

        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];

        [lineView release]; // IGNORE IF USING ARC
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"YOUR_TEXT"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: For the conscious, the color of the default iOS 7 separator seems to be 0xcccccc or RGB(204, 204, 204), and the default height `0.5` points, not `1.0`.

Answer (score 11):

You mean by manually Interface Builder ? if it's the case, click your UITableViewCell in IB and go to the third panel, in Separator insets choose custom and you can put the left and right value.
[image: Separator insets]

Edit : if you want to do it by code, see the documentation of UIEdgeInsets structure :
UIEdgeInsets 
Defines inset distances for views.

```
typedef struct {
   CGFloat top, left, bottom, right;
} UIEdgeInsets;
```

Then for example :

```
self.tableViewMain.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake (0, 15, 0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should negative value in the place of left inset

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake (0, -15, 0,0);
```

Comment: "Negative values are treated as if the inset is set to 0."  [UITableViewCell Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/separatorInset)